# No such module 'MapboxCommon_Private' / MapboxSearch / this SDK is not supported by the compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

So I cloned an existing repository from GitHub and tried the pods on my device(MacBook Pro M1 2020 bigSur 11.6 and Xcode 13) Cocoapods was not working as expected so I looked it up online and after trying to open using Rosetta and installing ffi gem I managed to install most of the pods. However, these 2 errors keep showing up:

- No such module 'MapboxCommon_Private'
- Failed to build module 'MapboxSearch'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.4.2 (swiftlang-1205.0.28.2 clang-1205.0.19.57)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.1 clang-1300.0.29.1)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

The pod file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '14.3'

post_install do |pi|
  pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
    t.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      config.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] =  `uname -m`
    end
  end
end

target 'Project' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Pods for Proiect
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
  pod 'XCoordinator', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'Reusable', '~> 4.1.1'
  pod 'SideMenu', '~> 6.0'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'NotificationBannerSwift'
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.8.0'
  pod 'CountryPickerView'
  pod 'SwiftGen', '~> 6.0'
  pod "RxGesture"
  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 6.2.1'
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 9.0'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod "CenteredCollectionView"
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod "RxRealm"
  pod 'MapboxSearch', ">= 1.0.0-beta.2", "< 2.0"
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 9.0'
  pod 'Wormholy', :configurations => ['dev debug', 'dev release']
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'JWTDecode', '~> 2.6'
  pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.4.0'
  pod 'DPOTPView'

  target 'Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
  target 'UITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
end
```

I also tried to downgrade the Xcode version to Xcode 12.5.1, and with the following pod file I got another error :

- Failed to build module 'MapboxSearch' from its module interface; it may have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift compiler when it was produced

the pod file :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.3'
post_install do |pi|
 pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
  t.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
   config.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = `uname -m`
   config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
 end
end
target 'Proiect' do
 # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!
 # Pods for Proiect
 pod 'RxSwift'
 pod 'RxCocoa'
 pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
 pod 'XCoordinator', '~> 2.0'
 pod 'Reusable', '~> 4.1.1'
 pod 'SideMenu', '~> 6.0'
 pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
 pod 'FacebookLogin'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
 pod 'NotificationBannerSwift'
 pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
 pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.8.0'
 pod 'CountryPickerView'
 pod 'SwiftGen', '~> 6.0'
 pod "RxGesture"
 pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 6.4.0'
 pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 9.0'
 pod 'DropDown'
 pod "CenteredCollectionView"
 pod 'RealmSwift'
 pod "RxRealm"
 pod 'MapboxSearch', ">= 1.0.0-beta.6", "< 2.0"
 pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 9.0'
 pod 'Wormholy', :configurations => ['dev debug', 'dev release']
 pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
 pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
 pod 'JWTDecode', '~> 2.6'
 pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.4.0'
 pod 'DPOTPView'
 target 'Tests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
 end
 target 'UITests' do
  # Pods for testing
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this pod was causing the problem:

```
pod 'MapboxSearch', ">= 1.0.0-beta.6", "< 2.0"
```

So I replaced it with:

```
pod 'MapboxSearch', "1.0.0-beta.4"
```

(Xcode and terminal running with Rosetta)